# Visual Studio 2008: Why Doesn't my Language Service Add-In Work? ("Sorry, parsing could not recover")

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1, languageservice

I'm trying to create my own language service in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, but when I run the program (which starts the Visual Studio Experimental Hive) and try to open a source file, I get this error:

[image: Package 'Microsoft VisualStudio CodeTools PropertyPage Package' has failed to load properly ( GUID = {072DD0C6-AE1E-4ED6-A0BF-B99D5B68D29E} ).]

Any ideas how to fix it? (I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS, it didn't work. :( )

---

## Update

It turns out this was due to a poor uninstallation of Spec#. I cleaned it up, but now the issue is that my language service doesn't actually highlight anything... I imagined this to be the cause, but seeing as how I still get the error and how it was irrelevant, I don't know what the problem is.

I'm using the default lexer/parser files with the default tokens, so I'd imagine there would be *some* sort of highlighting for my file types, but there isn't... any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: please post your "update" as a new question as it is not related to your original post and change back the title of the post to the original so other people with the same error can find this post.

Comment: Perhaps, you can add into the update how you found out a poor uninstallation of Spec# was the issue as part of your update to help other people out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it seems like it's working correctly:

```
if (x == 0)
{
}
```

is not even correct C code in the first place!

I was looking for syntax highlighting but I needed to set it up first, and it seems like it's working now.

Comment: So does that mean that the original question is answered?

Comment: Yeah, it's answered... I can't accept my own answer for 9 hours though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to take to get rid of this error:

- Uninstall Visual Studio 2008
- Uninstall all pre-release / beta software from your machine
- Use the [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack Preparation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A494B0E0-EB07-4FF1-A21C-A4663E456D9D&displaylang=en)
- Re-install Visual Studio 2008
- Re-install [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)
- Use [devenv.exe /resetskippkgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the command prompt while logged in as an admin user, before first starting Visual Studio 2008 SP1 after the re-installation.

The Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack Preparation Tool will help getting rid of pre-release versions of the SP1 software and other items which are known to cause issues, such as:

- Microsoft Silverlight Tools Beta 1
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - KB949325
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - KB944899 (v1)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - KB945140 (SP1 Beta)

If you encounter issues installing SP1, uninstall technologies and/or development add-ins not listed above, and then try SP1 Setup again. Only the following technologies have been tested and verified to work with SP1:

- Silverlight 2 SDK Beta 2 & Silverlight Tools Beta 2. (If Silverlight Tools Beta 2 is already installed, you must upgrade it after you install Visual Studio 2008 SP1. To upgrade, use the installer on the Silverlight Tools Beta 2 page on the Microsoft Download Center Web site.)
- MVC Preview Release #3
- ASP.NET Extensions/Dynamic Data Preview
- VC 2008 Feature Pack
- VB PowerPack Controls (2.0 & 3.0)
- Expression Studio 2 (RTM)
- SQL Server 2008
- .NET Framework 3.5 SDK
- XSLT Profiler
- VSTA 2.0 SDK
- Visual Studio 2008 SDK

Comment: @Mehrdad, try this and let me know if this helps! It did for me! :)

Comment: Thanks for the list. However, given that I didn't/don't have any beta/pre-release software on my machine, it seems like it all pretty much reduces down to "Uninstall Visual Studio 2008" and then "Reinstall Visual Studio 2008" and "Reinstall SP1", no? That's pretty much what I tried, except that I skipped installing SP1 the second time because it seems irrelevant to the error IMHO... so isn't this basically what I tried at first?

Comment: +1 since this helped me figure out it was an add-in problem. Now I'm trying to figure out what's preventing the language service from working, any thoughts?

Comment: @Mehrdad, there could be multiple causes for this error so it's better to go through all the steps to make sure you don't leave anything out. SP1 works with a limited list of technologies that I listed above. I would start with running "devenv.exe /resetskippkgs". If that doesn't work, I would go through your "programs and features" / "add or remove programs" and uninstall anything that you aren't familiar with and/or isn't listed above. I would also use the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack Preparation Tool. If that doesn't work, back-up your data, and reformat with a clean install of windows.